# Tabla dinamica con razor

Tags: c#, razor, blazor

Hola tengo una pregunta siguiendo el consejo en la pregutna de [Razor View dynamic table rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9198549/razor-view-dynamic-table-rows/63386928#63386928) de tabla dinámica, hice mi tabla con foreach pero no puedo conseguir crear nuevas columnas, si agredo un registro se pone en la misma columna, no hace un salto para otra columna(tener columnas con tres o n cantidad de productos y que si ya hay esa cantidad en ese calumnda que haga un salto y que se agregue en otra culumna y asi susecivamente), ¿Qué puedo hacer en este caso? Así tengo la vista en mi archivo de razor.

```
<div>
<table>
    <tr>
        @foreach (var item in product)
        {
            <td>
                <div class="card" style="width: 18rem; margin-top:3rem; margin-right:3rem; margin-bottom:2rem; margin-left:3rem; position:initial">
                    <img src="https://scontent.fntr8-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/107865247_704094323779323_2201784036865521556_n.jpg?_nc_cat=101&_nc_sid=8bfeb9&_nc_ohc=FwSgbE0cEAAAX92rcFt&_nc_ht=scontent.fntr8-1.fna&oh=4ec8b36ac7d0080b2f2bb3096b7b38cc&oe=5F37D400" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h2 class="card-title">@item.ProductName</h2>
                        <p class="card-text">@item.Description</p>
                        <h4 class="card-text">Stock</h4>
                        <p class="card-text">@item.UnitInStock</p>
                        <h4 class="card-text">Color</h4>
                        <p class="card-text">@item.Color</p>
                        <h3 class="card-text" style="align-content:center">$@item.Price</h3>
                        <p class="card-text">@item.CreationDate.ToShortDateString()</p>
                        <AuthorizeView>
                            <Authorized>
                                <a href="editproduct/@item.Id" class="btn btn-primary">Editar</a>
                                <button class="btn btn-danger" @onclick="@(() => EliminarProduct(item.Id))">Eliminar</button>
                            </Authorized>
                            <NotAuthorized>

                            </NotAuthorized>
                        </AuthorizeView>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
            count++;
            if (count % 3 == 0)
            {
                @:</tr>
                @:<tr>
            }
        }
    </tr>
</table>
```

Inserto una imagen del como esta por el momento
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Lo que hice fue solo dejar el  que tengo dentro del foreach y deje la validacion con el if. inserto codigo
Aclaracion el contandor o la variable que utilize count la inicialice en 1.

```
    @foreach (var item in product)
{
    <td>
        <div class="card" style="width: 18rem; margin-top:3rem; margin-right:3rem; margin-bottom:2rem; margin-left:3rem; position:initial">
            <img src="https://scontent.fntr8-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/107865247_704094323779323_2201784036865521556_n.jpg?_nc_cat=101&_nc_sid=8bfeb9&_nc_ohc=FwSgbE0cEAAAX92rcFt&_nc_ht=scontent.fntr8-1.fna&oh=4ec8b36ac7d0080b2f2bb3096b7b38cc&oe=5F37D400" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h2 class="card-title">@item.ProductName</h2>
                <p class="card-text">@item.Description</p>
                <h4 class="card-text">Stock</h4>
                <p class="card-text">@item.UnitInStock</p>
                <h4 class="card-text">Color</h4>
                <p class="card-text">@item.Color</p>
                <h3 class="card-text" style="align-content:center">$@item.Price</h3>
                <p class="card-text">@item.CreationDate.ToShortDateString()</p>
                <AuthorizeView>
                    <Authorized>
                        <a href="editproduct/@item.Id" class="btn btn-primary">Editar</a>
                        <button class="btn btn-danger" @onclick="@(() => EliminarProduct(item.Id))">Eliminar</button>
                    </Authorized>
                </AuthorizeView>
            </div>
        </div>
    </td>
    if ((count % 4) == 0 && count != product.Count())
    {
        @:<tr>
        @:</tr>
    }
    count++;
}
```